# Getting an image (eg svg) created on the client in javascript, back to the server side for c#

Tags: javascript, wcf, json, jsonp, highcharts

I'm looking at using a nice Javascript chart library like highcharts (www.highcharts.com) or D3 (http://mbostock.github.com/d3/).  These generate SVG or similar types of exhibit.

This is all very well for the browser, but I'd like to send people a 'summary' email with some of these charts embedded.  Presently I use a c# console app that generates the HTML, embeds the images (which are either picked up from the file system or rendered into memory by a server side chart control in).

My question is, to avoid recreating every chart on both server and client side, how could I get that 'client rendered' image back into my c# codebehind to attach to an email?  Is this in any way possible?  Would I need JSON?

Thanks!

Comment: In theory, you should be able to take your SVG image, draw it to a `<canvas>` element using `drawImage()` and then export the result to PNG using `canvas.toDataURL()`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work unless the SVG image resides on your server - if you generate the image on the client side and use a `data:` URL you get a security error as if you were trying to read out an image from another domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would help: https://github.com/imclem/Highcharts-export-module-asp.net

This is a ASP.NET exporting module for HighCharts. It takes client SVG-string as a parameter and generates JPEG/PNG and some other types of images. I think it would give you an idea.